# Non-Locally Integrable fundamental solutions

Tags: distribution-theory

Given a Linear pde $L$, a distribution $u$ is said to be a fundamental solution if $Lu=\delta$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta distribution. A common example is the Newtonian potential which is the fundamental solution of the Laplacian. Are there any examples of differential operators of positive order  with non-locally integrable fundamental solutions?

Comment: If it's not locally integrable, how would you differentiate it?

Comment: Any distribution can be differentiated,it doesn't have to be necessarily locally integrable

Comment: This is true but even in the distributional sense you run into issues since your natural space of test functions is going to be the bump functions. $\frac{d}{dx}$ maps the bump functions to themselves and so the inner product $\langle Du,\phi\rangle = -\langle u,D\phi\rangle$ isn't well-posed since the right side diverges since $u$ is not locally integrable. (I think.)

Comment: Cameron, $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot\right\rangle$ is not an inner product, $\left\langle \varphi,f\right\rangle$ for $\varphi\in D'$, $f\in D$ stands for $\varphi(f)$. And apart from that a fundamental solution is a distribution, so its maybe better to ask for "non regular fundamental solutions". Interesting question though. But I think yes, as if $E$ is a fundamental solution

Comment: $<u,D\phi>$ does make sense since u is a distribution and $D\phi$ a test function

Comment: @Heinz I know it's not an inner product I just didn't know what else to call it in a succinct way haha.

Comment: @harmonicuser but if $u$ is not locally integrable then $\langle u, D\phi\rangle$ is not a finite quantity.

Comment: Cameron: Consider the non regular distribution $\delta$. We have $\left\langle \delta, f\right\rangle =\delta(f)=f(0)$ which is "a finite quantity". Apart from that a fundamental solution is not unique, so one might try to find a non regular distributional solution of $Lu=0$, and add it to the fundamental solution (which will be again a fundamental solution)

Comment: @Heinz oh yeah I see your point. Makes sense. I was thinking strictly regular functions. In the context of regular functions, would my reasoning hold?

Comment: No, it would not. Maybe you are thinking about tempered distributions, in which case you are right. But in the non tempered case the integral $\int \varphi fdx$ with $\varphi\in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ is always well defined, since $f$ is assumed to be of class $C^\infty_0$ (compact support!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differential operator $1$ has $\delta$ as a fundamental solution, which is known to be non regular (not induced by a locally integrable function).

Also, the differential operator $x\partial/\partial x-1$ has $\delta$ as a fundamental solution, since $((x\partial/\partial x-1)\delta)(f)=\delta(-x\partial f/\partial x+f)=\delta(f)$. Are you looking for the constant coefficient case?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I was looking for an example where the order of the differential operator is greater than or equal to 1.I'll make the appropriate edit

Comment: alrite, I hope this is ok now

Comment: Now that you mentioned I'm curious if there is a constant coefficient example

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes. In 1999 Hörmander gave an example of a hypoelliptic operator
where the fundamental solution is not locally integrable. He also proves, among other things,
that no such counterexample exists in two dimensions.

This is the article:
On local integrability of fundamental solutions by Hörmander
Arkiv för Matematik 
Volume 37, Issue 1 , pp 121-140